# How to access information about specific user after login from MySQL in Java

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, authentication, user-profile

I've seen numerous explanations about this but in PHP. I'd like to do this in Java using JavaFX to support my GUI. I'll include my methods for Login and for showing user's name on docking station.

So lets say that I have 10 users in my database and user `login_id = 5` logs, that means that I'd like to get all information about him on certain places (ie. first name, last name, e-mail, etc.).

**LoginFXMLController**

```
@FXML
    private boolean loginSuccessful() throws SQLException{
        connection = MySQL.Connect();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = ? and password = ?";

        pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, tfUsername.getText());
        pst.setString(2, tfPassword.getText());
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        return (rs.next());
    }
```

**DockFXMLController**

```
@FXML
    public void showName()
    {
        try {
// Just getting info from login_id column, and not by specific user,
// and I'd like to change that
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM Login WHERE login_id = 1";
            pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next())
            {
                lblName.setText(rs.getString("first_name") + " " + rs.getString("last_name"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This code above works and shows what it's supposed to show - first name from first row, so I have properly initialized everything that I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing which class object "pst" actually is.
Here is a snapshot of   [java tutorial about database on java2s.com](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0340__Database/UpdatingaRowinaDatabaseTable.htm).

I think the problem is that You should call method createStatement().

I hope this might help you.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    String driverName = "com.jnetdirect.jsql.JSQLDriver";
    Class.forName(driverName);

    String serverName = "127.0.0.1";
    String portNumber = "1433";
    String mydatabase = serverName + ":" + portNumber;
    String url = "jdbc:JSQLConnect://" + mydatabase;
    String username = "username";
    String password = "password";

    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
    String sql = "UPDATE my_table SET col_string='a new string' WHERE col_string = 'a string'";
    int updateCount = stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

  }
}
```

Comment: `ResultSet rs` and `PreparedStatement pst` are objects that I've created. I'm not sure why should I `UPDATE` my table as I just have to find specific ID of a row and not to update it.